# Kurento don't starting streaming

Tags: kurento

I've created room video and use KMS. Sometimes (around 25%) stream not started.
I've checked response from server and debug FE part, but it's works same when all works fine.

Do you have any ideas?
I can provide more data if this nesesary.

Comment: can you please elaborate your question .

Comment: I'm and my team write conference call and use kurento. We have 3 clients. Android and Ios works, but on the web sometimes don't open data-channel. We check our code in web client but it's like group call kurento tutorial. Do you have some idea?

Comment: you want to perform group call or peer-peer call ?

Comment: we want  implement group call

Comment: it seems that you can perform group call in Android Native and IOS but not in Web Portal